# Drag & Drop needs a math fix

Tags: c#, silverlight

I have a drag/drop behavior for my RichTextBox in Silverlight 4, but i'm having a small snapping problem.

I would like the user to be able to "grab" any border of the RichTextBox and drag/drop it. The RichTextBox should drag relative to where the user "grabbed" the RichTextBox. But instead, as soon as the user begins the drag, the RichTextBox "snaps" to the middle of the mouse position instead of its position staying relative to the mouse position.

So if I grab the bottom right corner, as in the following ...

https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=DCC93DD825EF3F43!658

it "snaps" to the middle of the mouse position on the start of the dragging, as in the following ...

https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=DCC93DD825EF3F43!659

Here's my dragging code. I'm assuming my math is wrong (in the MouseMove event) ???

---

```
public class CustomRichTextBox : RichTextBox
{
    private bool isDragging = false;

    protected override void OnMouseLeftButtonDown(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseLeftButtonDown(e);

        bool isDragAllowed = false;
        Point pt = e.GetPosition(this);

        if (pt.Y >= 0 && pt.Y <= this.BorderThickness.Top)
            // Allow dragging if the mouse is down on the top border
            isDragAllowed = true;
        else if (pt.Y >= (this.RenderSize.Height - this.BorderThickness.Bottom) && pt.Y <= this.RenderSize.Height)
            // Allow dragging if the mouse is down on the bottom border
            isDragAllowed = true;
        else if (pt.X >= 0 && pt.X <= this.BorderThickness.Left)
            // Allow dragging if the mouse is down on the left border
            isDragAllowed = true;
        else if (pt.X >= (this.RenderSize.Width - this.BorderThickness.Right) && pt.X <= this.RenderSize.Width)
            // Allow dragging if the mouse is down on the right border
            isDragAllowed = true;

        if (!isDragAllowed)
            return;

        this.CaptureMouse();
        isDragging = true;
    }

    protected override void OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseMove(e);

        if (isDragging)
        {
            CustomRichTextBox elem = this;
            CompositeTransform ct = (CompositeTransform)elem.RenderTransform;
            UIElement parent = (UIElement)elem.Parent;

            ct.TranslateX = e.GetPosition(parent).X - (parent.RenderSize.Width / 2);
            ct.TranslateY = e.GetPosition(parent).Y - (parent.RenderSize.Height / 2);
        }
    }

    protected override void OnMouseLeftButtonUp(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseLeftButtonUp(e);

        isDragging = false;
        this.ReleaseMouseCapture();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is missing here is a **reference point** to the position where the drag began. In the mouse move event you're trying to translate the control to the current location of the mouse and not with the delta between the *current* and *original* locations.

Or by using relative coordinates you can store the location of the mouse click relatively to the control and simply substract it from the current one at OnMove. This is what happens in the sample below.

Note that this is WPF where there is no CompositeTransform.
Substracting the RenderSize of the parent looks like a mistake to me, or it may be a difference in WPF and Silverlight, anyway I hope this helps to work it out:

```
public class CustomRichTextBox : RichTextBox
{
    private bool isDragging = false;
    private Point draggingPoint;

    protected override void OnPreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(e);

        bool isDragAllowed = false;
        Point pt = e.GetPosition(this);

        if (pt.Y >= 0 && pt.Y <= this.BorderThickness.Top)
            // Allow dragging if the mouse is down on the top border
            isDragAllowed = true;
        else if (pt.Y >= (this.RenderSize.Height - this.BorderThickness.Bottom) && pt.Y <= this.RenderSize.Height)
            // Allow dragging if the mouse is down on the bottom border
            isDragAllowed = true;
        else if (pt.X >= 0 && pt.X <= this.BorderThickness.Left)
            // Allow dragging if the mouse is down on the left border
            isDragAllowed = true;
        else if (pt.X >= (this.RenderSize.Width - this.BorderThickness.Right) && pt.X <= this.RenderSize.Width)
            // Allow dragging if the mouse is down on the right border
            isDragAllowed = true;

        if (!isDragAllowed)
            return;

        draggingPoint = pt;

        this.CaptureMouse();
        isDragging = true;
    }

    protected override void OnPreviewMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPreviewMouseMove(e);

        if (isDragging)
        {
            CustomRichTextBox elem = this;
            TransformGroup ct = new TransformGroup();
            UIElement parent = (UIElement)elem.Parent;

            TranslateTransform tr = new TranslateTransform(
                e.GetPosition(parent).X - elem.RenderSize.Width + this.BorderThickness.Left - draggingPoint.X,
                e.GetPosition(parent).Y - elem.RenderSize.Height + this.BorderThickness.Top - draggingPoint.Y);

            ct.Children.Add(tr);

            elem.RenderTransform = ct;
        }
    }

    protected override void OnPreviewMouseLeftButtonUp(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPreviewMouseLeftButtonUp(e);

        isDragging = false;
        this.ReleaseMouseCapture();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much! That makes a lot of sense. I will go ahead and make the necessary changes   :)